# Changes to java code not being reflected in updated WAR for web project

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, gwt

I have a Java web application which was made by a colleague. I have been trying to make changes to the code of the project and deploy the same project in another location.

I have been doing the following:

1. Make required changes to Java source and save the changes
2. Build the web project
3. Deploy the newly generated WAR file using Apache Tomcat

However, the changes made to the code are not being reflected when I open the deployed web application in the browser.

I have tried to clean the project and build again, restart the server, reload the WAR, delete the related webapps folder. But it still remains the same. I also viewed the "last modified" time of the respective CLASS files and the times tamp also shows that the classes have been updated.

I run the build.xml file to generate the WAR. The build.xml file looks like this:

```
<project name="QA-SV-Web-regression" basedir="." default="default">

<target name="default" depends="buildwar,deploy"></target>

<target name="buildwar">
    <war basedir="war" destfile="WebReg.war" webxml="war/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <exclude name="WEB-INF/**" />
        <webinf dir="war/WEB-INF/">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </webinf>
    </war>
</target>

<target name="deploy">
    <copy file="WebReg.war" todir="." />
</target>
```

Please note: I am not using tomcat from eclipse. It is running as an independent application.

I am unable to figure out what to do to fix this issue. Please help.

---

Update: Whenever I am building the project, the CLASS files are being updated. I think the project is generating a valid output. However, the WAR still does not update the web content.

Comment: try `clean`ing the project and then build.

Comment: @karthik, I tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: Have you used this server using eclipse or other IDE earlier ?

Comment: does the build script steps rebuild the jars too or do you need a separate step.  Understand the build script thoroughly - start with e..g "ant -p".

Comment: @NaveenRamawat, yes, i had used the server previously with eclipse, but had not deployed any project with it.

Comment: Eclipse creates a deployment directory which is by default not same as the server deployment directory. So go to eclipse and open that server instance and change deployment directory to your actual server deployment directory.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, I only execute the build.xml file to build the project. I don't know if it builds the jars too. How can we check that?

Comment: @NaveenRamawat, what if I delete the server from eclipse?
Also, I forgot to mention, I had deployed the updated WAR in a different system as well. The problem persisted there as well. So I think it is not related to Tomcat.

Comment: It happened with me once when my eclipse set external deployment directory for server and I was trying to deploy on server deployment directory and was facing similar issue. If you are facing similar issue on different system than it might possible that you also copied your server from previous machine and that faulty directory might still giving you problem. get a fresh copy of server and deploy your war.

Comment: Can you export war from the eclipse and is it correct or not?

Comment: @NaveenRamawat, I had downloaded a new copy of the server in the other machine.

Comment: @nrvmodi, can you elaborate please?

Comment: From the Eclipse IDE, File-> Import/Export option . Can you export from it?

Comment: @nrvmodi, no. my project is not being listed when I try to export as WAR

Comment: You should invest the time needed to understand the build.xml file. It will pay off.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, from what observed is that the Jars are not being built again. Any way other than modifying the builds.xml to solve this issue?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, I changed the build.xml file. Re-wrote it completely. The problem still persists. So I am feeling now that the build process is not flawed. Something else is wrong. Please help!

Comment: Are the classes in the jar files in the war files updated correctly?

Comment: Yes. The classes in the war file are being updated correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Add clean,compile target in you build.xml and make your buildwar target depend on them if they are already not there. e.g.

```
<target name="buildwar" depends="clean,compile">
 ....
 </target>

 <target name="clean" >
 ....
 </target>

 <target name="compile" >
 ....
 </target>
```

Comment: In WAR file, you have web content (like html and javascript) and java classes. Where changes are not  reflected, java classes or webcontent ? Did you open the WAR file and checked whether changes are getting reflected in it or not?

Comment: Yes. I opened the WAR file. The changes are being reflected in the classes. But when I deploy the war, there are no visual changes to my application.

Comment: I had modified the source code to make some visual changes to the application. Upon deploying, those changes are not seen and I see the old setup, which should not be there.

Comment: Refresh the cache in that case. Generally such problems are fixed either by refreshing cache or restarting the application server.